# Else condition always works

Tags: python, if-statement

There is a bug in my code which I'm not able to identify. This code should return `True` if the list contains `[3,3]`.

But, if I write an `else` condition, it always shows `False`. If I skip the `else` condition, the code works fine.

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    pass
```

The above code returns :

```
# Check
has_33([1, 3, 3]) . -- > False

# Check
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) --> False.
```

But, if I change the code to this :

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
            return True
    pass
```

The code works fine :

```
# Check
has_33([1, 3, 3]) --> True

# Check
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) -- > Returns nothing , False.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Replace `pass` by `return False` and remove the `else` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the else condition is satisfied first. 
You have a for loop which goes over all the numbers in your list [1,3,3], first it check's the first number which is 1 and then the second number which is 3;

```
if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
```

In this case nums[i] is 1 which means nums[i]==3 is not True , which means your code will go straight to the `Else`

And the solution to your problem is simple:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:return True
    return False
```

Comment: yes! but it has the 2nd and 3rd item ==3, right ? doesn't it check them ?

Comment: No, it won't check them since the function already "returned" a value;If a value is returned in this case a False then the execution of the function stops. You simply have to put the `return False` outside the `for loop`. Which means that if the `if statement` inside the `for loop`  is not satisfied then the function will return false.

Comment: Cool. This answered my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers explain the bug pretty well. I did want to point out two things though.

1. A best practice in Python is to avoid iterating over a set of indices if possible, instead preferring to iterate over the object (e.g. `for n in nums`).
2. There are library functions that make your life substantially easier.

Consider the following code using the `any()` and `zip()` built-in functions.

```
def has_33(nums):
    return any(x==y==3 for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

If you wanted, you could make this more general so that it might be applicable in other projects. The use of a default value preserves the original behavior.

```
def has_duplicate(nums, val=3):
    return any(x==y==val for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this , The error occurring in your code because it will return and exit from code in the first loop itself. So you can give a flag and whenever the condition meets change the flag to true, then return the flag last:

```
def has_33(nums):
    flag = False
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
            flag = True

    return flag
```

Comment: Thank you @Vikas! Return should be out of the loop. Got it.

Comment: @MeghanaReddy happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also make small adjustment in your function and decrease an indentation of "else" statement this way:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]==3:
            return True
    else:
        return False
    pass
```

This is standard structure of "for" loop in Python - if your loop completes correctly without interruption (in your case - without finding two subsequent "3" on your list), it executes "else" statement.